# I don't understand why swapping two lines of code results in different Stopwatch measurements

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, concurrency

I have two similar pieces of code where Stopwatch measures time differently, i cannot understand why. Here are the cases:

**1. First case (sync part of method first) -**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DifferentTasks
{
    public class SyncAndAsyncPartsOfMethod
    {
        public async Task Execute()
        {
            IEnumerable<int> data = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);

            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Task t = Task.WhenAll(data.Select(AsyncAction));
            await t;
            stopwatch.Stop();

            double elapsedSeconds = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(
                stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds).TotalSeconds;

            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed seconds overall - " + elapsedSeconds);
        }
        
        private async Task AsyncAction(int x)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
            
            stopwatch.Stop();
                
            double elapsedSeconds = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(
                stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds).TotalSeconds;
                
            Console.WriteLine($"AsyncAction {x} is finished" +
                $", elapsed seconds - {elapsedSeconds}" +
                $", thread - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }
    }
}
```

Elapsed seconds overall - 102 seconds

`AsyncAction` method stopwatch elapsed time -

```
AsyncAction 95 is finished, elapsed seconds - 2,046, thread - 5
AsyncAction 96 is finished, elapsed seconds - 2,032, thread - 4
AsyncAction 97 is finished, elapsed seconds - 2,015, thread - 4
AsyncAction 98 is finished, elapsed seconds - 2,029, thread - 4
AsyncAction 99 is finished, elapsed seconds - 2,046, thread - 5
```

**2. Second case (async part of method first) -**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DifferentTasks
{
    public class SyncAndAsyncPartsOfMethod
    {
        public async Task Execute()
        {
            IEnumerable<int> data = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);

            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Task t = Task.WhenAll(data.Select(AsyncAction));
            await t;
            stopwatch.Stop();

            double elapsedSeconds = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(
                stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds).TotalSeconds;

            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed seconds overall - " + elapsedSeconds);
        }
        
        private async Task AsyncAction(int x)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            
            stopwatch.Stop();
                
            double elapsedSeconds = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(
                stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds).TotalSeconds;
                
            Console.WriteLine($"AsyncAction {x} is finished" +
                $", elapsed seconds - {elapsedSeconds}" +
                $", thread - {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }
    }
}
```

Elapsed seconds overall - 13 seconds

`AsyncAction` method stopwatch elapsed time (it seems to be accumulative and increasing) -

```
AsyncAction 92 is finished, elapsed seconds - 3,066, thread - 6
AsyncAction 89 is finished, elapsed seconds - 4,035, thread - 8
AsyncAction 87 is finished, elapsed seconds - 4,082, thread - 6
AsyncAction 85 is finished, elapsed seconds - 4,082, thread - 5
AsyncAction 83 is finished, elapsed seconds - 5,051, thread - 8
AsyncAction 81 is finished, elapsed seconds - 5,067, thread - 4
```

Code to start these class -

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DifferentTasks
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SyncAndAsyncPartsOfMethod syncAndAsyncPartsOfMethod = new();
            syncAndAsyncPartsOfMethod.Execute().Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to understand what is the difference between these two cases and why does it work like this.

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds).TotalSeconds;` <-- \*disappointedface\*

Comment: What "inner stopwatch" are you referring to?

Comment: @Dai what's the problem with this line?

Comment: Because `stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds`

Comment: Your output does not match your program - your program has `Enumerable.Range( 0, 5 )` but your output says `92...81` - and prints `ThreadId` values. Please show us your actual program source-code

Comment: @Dai you're right, sorry for that, i have edited the question

Comment: That's a very strange code snippet

Comment: @Progman thank you, i have already edited it, don't  know if you can see it or not - the post was submitted for review several minutes ago

Comment: Looks to me like the difference between the two snippets is you've changed the order of these two lines, `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` and `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));`, and this results in a difference in overall execution time?

Comment: @Idle_Mind yeah, i know that lines order is changed:) I don't understand how it affects elapsed time, measured by stopwatches.

Comment: Of course you know! My comment was meant more for OTHERS reading your question to be able to understand the difference. It was not clear to me what the difference was when I first read your question. I had to read it multiple times and stare at the two code snippets a lot until it became clear what the difference/issue was...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to understanding the behavioral difference is the line below:

```
Task t = Task.WhenAll(data.Select(AsyncAction));
```

Let's dissect it. Functionally it is equivalent to the `foreach` loop below:

```
List<Task> tasks = new();
foreach (int item in data)
{
    Task task = AsyncAction(item);
    tasks.Add(task);
}
Task t = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

So in order to get the final task `t`, you must first invoke the `AsyncAction` for all 100 elements in the `data` sequence. In your first example the `AsyncAction` starts with these two lines:

```
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

In your second example the two lines are reversed:

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

In your first example the `AsyncAction` blocks the current thread for one second before returning an incomplete `Task`. On the contrary in your second example the `AsyncAction` returns an incomplete `Task` immediately. That's the difference. In your first example the task `t` is created after 100 seconds, while in your second example the task `t` is created practically instantly. You could verify this by using a `Stopwatch` before and after the `Task t = Task.WhenAll(data.Select(AsyncAction));` line.

In case you are wondering why the `AsyncAction` does not return invariably an incomplete `Task` immediately, that's because of how the `async` methods are working. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) (emphasis added):

> An async method **runs synchronously** until it reaches its first `await` expression, at which point the method is suspended until the awaited task is complete. In the meantime, control returns to the caller of the method.